# Implement apple.ldif in an openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I'm currently running an openldap server on a debian machine

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:    8.7
Codename:   jessie
```

Slapd version

```
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Jan 16 2016 23:00:08) $
    root@chimera:/tmp/buildd/openldap-2.4.40+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd
```

I've transform the [official](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-186/OpenLDAP/servers/slapd/schema/apple.schema.auto.html) schema into an ldif with following tutorial [here](https://www.lisenet.com/2015/convert-openldap-schema-to-ldif/)

Worked perfectly my kerberos ldifs, but when I try to apply the apple.ldif, I encounter a

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=apple,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: olcObjectClasses: AttributeType not found: "acctFlags"
```

So far, some blogs say that this isn't a critical attribute, and could be directly removed.

**I wanted to know if that's "normal" to just remove some attributes directly from the official schema (same schema I can also get from directly some iMacs in the infrastructure) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it's not normal to remove attributes. If you're missing an attribute it usually means you're missing some other dependent schema.

In this case it looks like Apple's [samba schema](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-186/OpenLDAP/servers/slapd/schema/samba.schema.auto.html). This may in turn rely on other schema, but I suspect they've provided the [complete set](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-186/OpenLDAP/servers/slapd/schema/).

Answer (score 3):

This question and 84104's answer ended up pointing me in the right direction. `apple.schema` doesn't list its dependencies, but most (if not all) of [the others](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenLDAP/OpenLDAP-186/OpenLDAP/servers/slapd/schema/) do.

Here are the schemas I needed to load (and in this order) to satisfy all the dependencies and convince slapd to load `apple.schema`:

```
core.schema
cosine.schema
inetorgperson.schema
nis.schema
samba.schema
apple_auxillary.schema
apple.schema
```